# How can I publish custom broker messages in minos?

Tags: python, microservices, broker, minos

I want to send a message to notify about something in one of my microservices, but I don't want to do that through a domain event, which requires to create, update or delete one of the entities of the microservice.

Is there another way to send a message such that another microservices can handle them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! You can do that directly using the `BrokerPublisher` instance injected in the corresponding service.

If you want to send a message you can do as follows:

```py
from minos.common import ModelType
from minos.cqrs import Service
from minos.networks import Request, enroute


MyContent = ModelType.build("MyContent", {"text": str, "number": int})


class MySenderService(Service):

    @enroute.rest.command("/send/my-channel", "POST")
    async def handle_send_my_channel(self, request: Request) -> Response:
        
        # First, create the message.
        message = BrokerMessageV1(
            "MyChannel", BrokerMessageV1Payload(MyContent("foo", 56))
        )

        # Then, send it!
        await self.broker_publisher.send(message)
```

In this case, `"MyChannel"` refers to the channel (or topic) on which the message will be sent.

Note that `MyContent` is a convenient `ModelType` created just to give the message's content some structure (but it could be another type, like `int`, `str`, `dict` and so on).

Finally, if you want to handle it in another microservice, you can do that as any other message:

```py
from minos.cqrs import Service
from minos.networks import Request, enroute


class MyReceiverService(Service):

    @enroute.broker.event("MyChannel")
    async def handle_my_channel(self, request: Request):

        # Print the received message's content!
        print(await request.content())
```